# Vue.js - Iterating through data objects on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, iterator, vue-component

I am trying to create a quiz using vue.js and cannot seem to figure out how to make the "Next" button iterate through my data. The hope is for the screen to display the object containing the question with answers (i.e. questionOne, questionTwo), then show the next object when "Next" is clicked. I have several attempts in the existing code as you will see, but none work.

Quiz Component Template:

```
<template>
  <div class="quiz-container">
    <div
      class="question-container">
      <h1> {{ currentQuestion.q }} </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="answer-container">
      <v-btn
        v-for="answer in currentQuestion.ans"
        :key="answer"
        outlined
        block
        x-large
        class="answer-btn"
      >
      {{ answer }}
      </v-btn>
    </div>
    <div
      class="navigation flex-row"
    >
      <v-btn text x-large @click="questionNav.curr--">Back</v-btn>
      <v-spacer />
      <v-btn text x-large @click="qNext()">Next</v-btn>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Quiz Script:

```
<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
  export default {
    name: 'quiz',
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters('user', {
        loggedIn: 'loggedIn'
      })
    },
    data: () => ({
      curr: 0,
      currentQuestion: {
         q: 'kasjdn' ,
         ans: ['1', '2', '3']
      },
      questionOne: {
         q: 'How many minutes do you want to spend?' ,
         ans: ['Short (15-20)', 'Medium (20-40)', 'Long (40-60)']
      },
      questionTwo: {
         q: 'What muscle group do you want to focus on?' ,
         ans: ['Upper Body', 'Lower Body', 'Core', 'Full Body']
      },
      questionThree: {
         q: 'What level intensity do you want?' ,
         ans: ['Leisure Walking', 'Speed Walking', 'Jogging', 'Sprinting']
      },
      questionParts: [this.questionOne, this.questionTwo, this.questionThree]
    }),
    methods: {
      questionNav: function () {
        questionParts = [this.questionOne, this.questionTwo, this.questionThree]
        currentQuestion = questionParts[curr]
      },
      qNext: function () {
        this.currentQuestion = this.questionParts[this.curr++]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

As you can see, I have tried a "qNext" method and a "questionNav" method, but neither work. Again, I would like for the "Next" to iterate through [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree]. I am relatively new to vue, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with you referring your main objects properties using 'this' inside of a function. 'this' is context specific so in your methods, it will be the method object not your main method

Comment: @GlynnHurrell I initially had them without "this", but that didn't work either

Comment: without using this, they would be local properties. Have you tried passing 'this' into the functions constructor so qNext: function(obj) { obj.currentQuestion = obj.questionParts[obj.curr++] } and then calling qNext(this)

Comment: @GlynnHurrell no, but I will try that now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the current implementation is that you're trying to populate `questionParts` in a context where `questionOne`, `questionTwo` and `questionThree` aren't accessible, meaning that your questions array will be filled with undefined values.

Overall, what you've done should work as long as you make sure `questionParts` does contain the question objects. If you want to keep that logic in the `data` method, here's how you could go about it:

```js
data: () => {
  const questionOne = {
    q: 'How many minutes do you want to spend?' ,
    ans: ['Short (15-20)', 'Medium (20-40)', 'Long (40-60)']
  };
  const questionTwo = {
    q: 'What muscle group do you want to focus on?' ,
    ans: ['Upper Body', 'Lower Body', 'Core', 'Full Body']
  };
  const questionThree = {
    q: 'What level intensity do you want?' ,
    ans: ['Leisure Walking', 'Speed Walking', 'Jogging', 'Sprinting']
  };
  const questionParts = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree]
  return {
    curr: 0,
    currentQuestion: {
      q: 'kasjdn' ,
      ans: ['1', '2', '3']
    },
    questionOne,
    questionTwo,
    questionThree,
    questionParts,
  }
},
```

By declaring a few variables before actually return `data()`'s value, you're able to properly populate the `questionParts` array. This should be sufficient to get your quiz to work.

There are a few other improvements that you might want to consider, for example:

- Instead of declaring `questionOne`, `questionTwo` and `questionThree` objects, you could instantiate an array of questions directly. Given the code example you provided, it doesn't seem especially useful to have each question as a distinct object.
- `currentQuestion` could be a computed property that returns the question at index `curr`. You would then be able to only increment or decrement `curr` in the click handlers, and the computed property would take care of returning the correct question without you needing to explicitly assign `currentQuestion`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and also the great optimization advice!

Answer (score 0):

```js
qNext: function () {
        this.currentQuestion.q = this.questionParts[this.curr++].q
        this.currentQuestion.ans = this.questionParts[this.curr++].ans
      }
```